# Is there a simple way to only show ads on a WordPress page once it becomes popular?

Tags: ads

I am looking for a simple way to minimize ads on a website I'm developing in WordPress by only showing ads (Google Adsense, to be precise) on the site upon a large influx of traffic.  A large influx as defined as, say, more than 2x the normal hourly traffic (though the exact metric used to determine popularity is not that important to me).

In other words, if ever the site sees a huge influx of traffic, I would like to begin delivering ads (to attempt to cover the incremental server costs).  Otherwise, I would like to keep the site ad-free for the casual visitors.

Is there a simple way, or plug-in, to do this in WordPress?

Comment: WordPress doesn't do any traffic tracking itself. You should edit your question to include what stats package(s) you're using, as that's going to determine what data is available and how/whether it can be used. Also, the question flips back and forth between a *post* getting high traffic and the whole *site* getting high traffic. You might want to clarify which you're actually asking about.

Comment: Furthermore, define 'popular' and 'huge influx'.

Comment: Wordpress has their own tracking plugin called statpress. You can download and use it from wordpress jetpack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one wordpress plugin called "[Search ads](http://www.dailyblogtips.com/search-ads-wordpress-plugin/)" that lets you do this. You can show adsense ads only to search engine users, which usually click on ads. As for regular readers from sources like bookmarks and manual address typing, ads will not show. Another plugin is "[ad injection](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ad-injection/)".

If you wish to do adsense tracking on any website then you have to connect google adsense with google analytics profile. You have to use the tracking code of that profile on site which has adsense enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to put ads the go for it.  Why serve ad only part of the time.  That does not make sense.  Even the biggest sites on the web serve adsense ads all the time.

The best you could do is get a plugin that show ads during a specific time period if need be.

Or just keep your site ad free.  Or there are other ways to make money outside adsense.

Throw up a banner or two.  Sell a link.  Think outside the box if you need to cover costs.

But in my opinion a popular site should run adsense 24/7

Comment: -1 Read the question. The point is specifically to *minimize* ads. Your opinion that ads should be maximized is irrelevant.